# Linux-Kernel-Modules : Built-in module working with the old modules.dep file in the file-system

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, kernel-module, texas-instruments

I have built a modules as built-in and correspondingly modified the 'dtb' file to make the hrdware discoverable to the kernel. The process which is being followed is as,

1. Modified kernel configuration for 'xyz' driver to built the same as built-in module
2. Correspondingly modified the dtb file
3. In the target device placed the new 'uImage' and 'dtb' file through **scp** command

Here the file  i.e. '**modules.dep**' is not replaced and it's old

Question: Is modules.dep file required to be updated for built-in module to work and appear on '/sys/class/drm/' folder

Comment: Here the driver which is built-in shall appear as a device in /sys/class/drm/

Comment: As far as I know, the modules.dep file is only used by the userspace tools for loading modules.